# Exception in the Android's code while starting the app

Tags: android, exception

In the "Crashes and ANRs" of the Google Play Developer console I've got such a report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.res.Resources.getAssets()' on a null object reference
at android.app.LoadedApk.getAssets(LoadedApk.java:590)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5088)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

The device that has this problem is Galaxy S4 and runs Android 5.0

What it can be - **there is not a single line from my code**, why does it fail?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: But your app runs normally on your device/the devices of most of your users?

Comment: Yes. But I've deployed it to production recently, so there is not much statistics.

Comment: Just to make sure - You've tested it on 5.0, right?

Comment: Yes. It goes all right on several known 5.0 devices

Comment: I experienced this too, and this happened quite often. `getAssets()` is not from our code, it is from OS's code. Most likely it is this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56296. Star that in order to get more attention.

Comment: I just have got the same error, is there any new solution of that error?

Answer (score 4):

I've got this in my console too.
It seems this occurs when users start the app when it's currently being updated or just after that.

A possible workaround would be to check if getResources returns null when the application start, and kill it if it does:

```
public class DevToolsApplication extends Application { 
    private static final String TAG = "DevToolsApplication"; 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() { 
        super.onCreate(); 
        AppLogger.i(TAG, "app start..."); 
        checkAppReplacingState(); 
    } 

    private void checkAppReplacingState() { 
        if (getResources() == null) { 
            AppLogger.w(TAG, "app is replacing...kill"); 
            Process.killProcess(Process.myPid()); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

See this for more information
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36972466

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that anywhere you call `getAssets()`, you call it as:

```
getApplicationContext().getAssets()
```

It would appear as if you are calling `getAssets()` in a class that does not have the application context available, hence the fact that it is null.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I don't call to getAssets() anywhere. By the way - assets folder of my app is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same exception while added the below overlay in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Even after removing the Overlay code, landed into the above exception.

```
<overlay android:targetPackage="com.android.systemui"
             android:priority="1"/>
```

Just close the Android Studio completely. Open the project again. Clean and Build the exception got cleared.